# Calling Postgres stored procedure in Shell

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to convert the below Oracle stored procedure called from shell script to Postgres. Can someone help me out on what to change to make it work in shell for Postgress? v_err_code and v_err_msg are OUT parameters.

--- Begin Postgres stored procedure from shell ----

```
load_result=$(psql -d ${PG_DB} -c "
   var v_err_code    INTEGER;
   var v_err_msg     TEXT;

   CALL testuser.test_pkg.MAIN('$P_param1', :v_err_code, :v_err_msg);

   print v_err_code
   print v_err_msg

   exit;
");

echo "load_result= $load_result"
```

--- End Postgres stored procedure from shell ----

--- Begin Oracle stored procedure from shell ----

```
load_result=`${ORACLE_HOME}/bin/sqlplus -silent $CONNECT_STRING <<EOF

set heading off
set feedback off

variable v_err_code      number;
variable v_err_msg       varchar2(4000)

execute testuser.test_pkg.MAIN('$P_param1', :v_err_code, :v_err_msg);

print v_err_code
print v_err_msg

exit;
EOF`

echo "load_result= $load_result"
```

--- End Oracle stored procedure from shell ----

Comment: `psql` does not have `var`, `print`, or `exit` commands

Comment: Thanks, What is the alternate way of printing/transfering the values of OUT parameters into in shell variables?